# How to parse a particular array of object using gson?

Tags: java, android, gson

I want to get a JSON array of object in JSON using Gson library, but here I have an issue to how to get access particular JSON array in nested JSON array. This is how I am trying:

My Model Class:

```
public class ComposeSMSList {

@SerializedName("userMessages")
@Expose
private List<UserMessage> userMessages = null;
@SerializedName("userPhoneBooks")
@Expose
private List<UserPhoneBook> userPhoneBooks = null;
@SerializedName("usersSendorIds")
@Expose
private List<UsersSendorId> usersSendorIds = null;
@SerializedName("userTemplates")
@Expose
private List<UserTemplate> userTemplates = null;

public List<UserMessage> getUserMessages() {
    return userMessages;
}

public void setUserMessages(List<UserMessage> userMessages) {
    this.userMessages = userMessages;
}

public List<UserPhoneBook> getUserPhoneBooks() {
    return userPhoneBooks;
}

public void setUserPhoneBooks(List<UserPhoneBook> userPhoneBooks) {
    this.userPhoneBooks = userPhoneBooks;
}

public List<UsersSendorId> getUsersSendorIds() {
    return usersSendorIds;
}

public void setUsersSendorIds(List<UsersSendorId> usersSendorIds) {
    this.usersSendorIds = usersSendorIds;
}

public List<UserTemplate> getUserTemplates() {
    return userTemplates;
}

public void setUserTemplates(List<UserTemplate> userTemplates) {
    this.userTemplates = userTemplates;
}

}
```

Now I want to access the user phone book class from the parent class.
Is there any elegant way to do this?

My code:

```
Gson mGson=new Gson();
List<ComposeModel> posts=Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response.toString(),ComposeModel.class));

for (int i=0;i<posts.size();i++){
    ComposeModel object = new  ComposeModel(posts.get(i).getComposeSMSList().getUserMessages().get(i).getId(),posts.get(i).getComposeSMSList().getUserMessages().get(i).getMessage());
    global.add(object);
}
mUserMsgAdpater=new UserMsgAdpater(mContext,global);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserMsgAdpater);
```

Comment: Could you insert the structure of your json?

Comment: "userMessages": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "message": "TODAY'S PHILOSOPHY HONEY DROPS:\n*// \"Thanathu thavarai thaney unargiravan buthisaali!\" \\\\*\n-BHAGAWAN SHREESATHYAM\nsrisathyaashram@gmail.com"
            },]"userPhoneBooks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "phonebookGroupname": "ISKON",
                "nrOfContacts": 2924
            },]

Comment: i have four array in my json now i want to access user phone book array from  entire json array how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your ComposeModel class? Anyway, the Json that you inserted in your comment is incomplete. I supposed is something like this:

**ComposeSMS.json**

```
{
  "userMessages":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "message":"this is a message"
    }
  ],
  "userPhoneBooks":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "phonebookGroupname":"ISKON",
      "nrOfContacts":2924
    }
  ],
  "usersSendorIds":[
    {
      "id":1
    }
  ],
  "userTemplates":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "templateName":"aTemplate"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you have your **ComposeSMSList** class:

```
    public class ComposeSMSList {

    private List<UserMessage> userMessages = null;
    private List<UserPhoneBook> userPhoneBooks = null;
    private List<UsersSendorId> usersSendorIds = null;
    private List<UserTemplate> userTemplates = null;

    public List<UserMessage> getUserMessages() {
        return userMessages;
    }

    public void setUserMessages(List<UserMessage> userMessages) {
        this.userMessages = userMessages;
    }

    public List<UserPhoneBook> getUserPhoneBooks() {
        return userPhoneBooks;
    }

    public void setUserPhoneBooks(List<UserPhoneBook> userPhoneBooks) {
        this.userPhoneBooks = userPhoneBooks;
    }

    public List<UsersSendorId> getUsersSendorIds() {
        return usersSendorIds;
    }

    public void setUsersSendorIds(List<UsersSendorId> usersSendorIds) {
        this.usersSendorIds = usersSendorIds;
    }

    public List<UserTemplate> getUserTemplates() {
        return userTemplates;
    }

    public void setUserTemplates(List<UserTemplate> userTemplates) {
        this.userTemplates = userTemplates;
    }
}
```

You can deserialize your json in this way:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String filename="/pathTo.../composeSMS.json";
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
        ComposeSMSList composeSMSList= gson.fromJson(reader, ComposeSMSList.class);
        System.out.println("composeSMSList: " + gson.toJson(composeSMSList));
```

In your question you ask to access the UserPhoneBook, but in your code you try with the UserMessage.

Anyway, you can access in this way:

```
       List<UserPhoneBook> userPhoneBooks= composeSMSList.getUserPhoneBooks();
       for(UserPhoneBook upb: userPhoneBooks)
        {
            System.out.println("UserPhoneBook id: " + upb.getId());
            System.out.println("UserPhoneBook nrOfContacts: " +upb.getNrOfContacts());
            System.out.println("UserPhoneBook phonebookGroupname: " +upb.getPhonebookGroupname());
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your response i try this then let you know